# Calculating multiple deductions based on more than 1 criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

What I'm basically trying to do is calculate what deduction will be made from a pot of money based on 2 different certain criteria NOT being met. If the individual does not achieve 2 validated data meetings or 2 validated mobile meetings, then they are deducted 25% off of their total commission value per criteria not met. What I've written has just come back with "TRUE", but doesn't show me that because someone hit 1 of the criteria and not the other that it will be a 25% deduction.

I've written this formula:

```
=IF(E23<2,1-0.75,+AND(OR(F23<2,1-0.75)))
```

If I change the number in E23 to 1, then it shows 25%, but not when the criteria in E23 has been met but not the criteria in F23 - I basically want it to calculate the total % deduction from both criteria

[image]

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Comment: Hi David, I hope that works :)

Comment: Your logic is a little ambiguous.  This might be easier to understand if you express it in terms of what must happen rather than conditions in which it doesn't.  Do that for each result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the two deductions separately first, and only then add them:

```
=IF(E23<2, 0.25, 0) + IF(F23<2, 0.25, 0)
```

The above reads "if E23 (data meetings) is less than 2, then 0.25 (deductions), otherwise, 0 (deductions), then add this result to: if F23 (mobile meetings) is less than 2, then 0.25 (deductions), otherwise, 0 (deductions)".

This means:

- only data meetings less than 2 will give 25% deduction
- only mobile meetings less than 2 will give 25% deduction
- both data and mobile meetings less than 2 will give 50% deduction
- neither data and mobile meetings less than 2 will give 0% deduction

Answer (score 0):

*You may use this Formula also:*

```
=IF(AND(E23<2,F23<2),E20*0.5,IF(OR(E23<2,F23<2),E20*0.25,0))
```

**Note:**

- Cell `E20` has a value, for that the formula calculates certain  percent based on criteria.
- Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.